# Initial message on Socket connect

Tags: java, sockets

trying to connect via TCP to a server using java sockets, the connection gets refused. I'm supposed to send a key to authenticate. code:

```
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
    clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("server.address.whatever", 123456));

    System.out.println("Connected");

    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String key = "key";
    outToServer.writeBytes(key + "\r\n");
    String response = inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + response);
    clientSocket.close();
```

It never makes it to the point where it tries to print out "Connected", it throws

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

So i never send the key. What am i missing here? How can i send an initial message during connecting? Am i even supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is no server process listening on that socket. Check whether you can make a connection with a tool like nmap (or just telnet).

Comment: Tried on my android phone using TCP Client app, for a brief moment it says connected, after that "recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)", in telnet: Connection refused

Comment: Telnet "connection refused" means it can't even make an initial connection - either because a firewall is blocking it or because nothing is listening at that address.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the server. The other side fixed it and it works now :)